# JqueryUI: dialog opening causes select list to close

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an .on("click"... event for my select that opens a dialog.

The problem is that the opening of the dialog closes the select that the user has just clicked.

How can I stop this closing of the select list? I am testing on FF16 and jqueryui 1.9

Here is an example and JSfiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/HqfvP

```
$(function(){
  $('#theDialog').dialog( {
      autoOpen : false,
      resizable : false,
      stack : false, position: ['right','center']
  });
  $("#theSelect").on("click", function(){
      $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");//closes all open dialogs
      $('#theDialog').dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the select options close is because `.dialog("open")` automatically sets focus to an element on the dialog. Not wanting to set focus on a newly opened dialog is an unusual use case, so you'll have to do some customization: http://jsfiddle.net/HqfvP/3/

The linked code looks like it might have been a lot of work, but really wasn't terribly hard to come up with:
1. Extend the jQuery dialog like this:

```
$.widget("ui.my_dialog", $.ui.dialog, { 
});
```

1. Change all of the `.dialog` references to `.my_dialog`
2. Copy the `open` function from the jQuery UI [source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js) into my new object.
3. *(Optional)* Rename `open` to `open_nofocus` (or something else) and update uses of `open`.

Comment: Does .dialog have to be renamed? Would it be just as good, if not cleaner to just add an "open_nofocus" to existing.dialog

Comment: That does, at least, appear to work: http://jsfiddle.net/HqfvP/4/ My personal preference would be to know I'm not working with the standard jQuery UI widget.